# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'

Tags: android, build.gradle, jack

Well i have some weird kind of run error, There is no error in the code neither in the gradle build. Get me through this

here is my app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kpitb.manxoor.kpitbforpocket"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my project level build

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

while compiling the app Gradle build show this error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.

> Cannot load Jill from build tools.

Comment: after changing according to my answer it will not work please update latest android studio

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kpitb.manxoor.kpitbforpocket"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation  'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my project level build

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```